# Remix Compiler Errors - Transferred GitHub .SOL Codes to Remix

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, testing, compiler

I transferred all 23 Sol extension files (smart contracts for Syscoin and Ether) from GitHub to Remix but only 3 of them can be compiled and deployed. The rest of them show errors.
[Here is the link for the .Sol codes: **https://github.com/syscoin/sysethereum-contracts/tree/master/contracts**]

**What am I doing wrong?**
**Here are 4 error message examples (displayed on Remix compiler):**
Error message from SyscoinBattleManager.sol is: "not found browser/SyscoinParser/SyscoinMessageLibrary.sol"

Error message from SyscoinClaimManager.sol is: "Unable to import "@openzeppelin/upgrades/contracts/Initializable.sol": File not found"

Error message from SyscoinDepositsManager.sol is: "Unable to import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol": File not found"

Error message from SycoinSuperblocks.sol is: "not found browser/SyscoinParser/SyscoinMessageLibrary.sol"

Comment: The problem is that project expect an directory struct and it is difficult to recreate within remix. For example the library "SyscoinMessageLibrary" has to be created as "SyscoinParser/SyscoinMessageLibrary.sol" for directory "SyscoinParser" to exist. More complex is the situation of files in "@openzeppelin" directory, they are a lot of files. Perhaps one solution is to download the project to your computer an use remixd to share the folder with remix.

Comment: Thanks for your input but what is "remixd"?                          How would I use remixd to share the folder with remix? Can you give a step by step guide? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Ismael, did you mean using Remix Desktop?                                 https://github.com/ethereum/remix-desktop/releases/tag/v1.0.3-beta.5

Comment: [RemixD](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remixd.html) is a plugin that allows sharing a local folder with Remix ide. In my experience remix is not very good for complex projects, it used to crash frequently.

Comment: Thanks! So would you recommend that I use Github Desktop and then access files from there using the global RemixD command:                                                                                         npm install -g remixd ?

Comment: Syscoin appears to use truffle, I'd use git to clone in a local directory and truffle compiling and testing contract.

Comment: Thanks! I hope I'll be able to figure out how to use Truffle.

Comment: Git clone on Heroku right?

Comment: I don't know what is heroku, I'd use git from the command line to clone the repo in a local directory.

Comment: Okay I did what you suggested. The repo is now cloned to a local directory (I used GitHub Desktop). For Truffle, I downloaded both Node JS and Ganache. How do I compile and deploy the SysCoin smart contracts (from GitHub) using those programs?

Comment: Comments are not a good place for long interactions. Check the project readme file. Ask in their channels. They used to be very active.